# Why do I get Memory Error in stringsource?

Tags: python, multithreading, cython, joblib, memmap

I am trying to execute a cython file in parallel. The skeleton of my code is:

```py
def build_DF_single(lo, hi, map[long, set[string]] authors_id_map, map[long, set[string]] authors_org_map, 
    map[long, set[string]] fos_name_map, map[long, set[string]] publisher_map, 
    map[long, set[string]] year_map, map[long, set[long]] reference_map, 
    map[string, double] authors_id_prob, map[string, double] authors_org_prob, 
    map[string, double] fos_name_prob, map[string, double] publisher_prob, 
    map[string, double] year_prob, map[string, set[long]] authors_id_co, 
    map[string, set[long]] authors_org_co, map[string, set[long]] fos_name_co, 
    map[string, set[long]] publisher_co, map[string, set[long]] year_co, 
    map[long, vector[double]] doc2vec_map):

    for i in tqdm(range(lo, hi)):
        line = lines[i]
        # Data cleaning on <line>

def mmap(name):
    d = joblib.load("mmap/" + name + ".mmap", mmap_mode="r")
    gc.collect()
    return d

authors_id_prob = mmap("authors_id_prob")
authors_org_prob = mmap("authors_org_prob")
fos_name_prob = mmap("fos_name_prob")
publisher_prob = mmap("publisher_prob")
year_prob = mmap("year_prob")
authors_id_co = mmap("authors_id_co")
authors_org_co = mmap("authors_org_co")
fos_name_co = mmap("fos_name_co")
publisher_co = mmap("publisher_co")
year_co = mmap("year_co")
doc2vec_map = mmap("doc2vec_map")

with open("file", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() # Pretty large as well
batch_size = int(math.ceil(len(lines) / n_cpu))
results = Parallel(n_jobs = n_cpu, prefer="threads", max_nbytes=None)(delayed(build_DF_single)(
    (i * batch_size), min((i + 1) * batch_size, len(lines)),
    authors_id_map, authors_org_map, fos_name_map, publisher_map, year_map, reference_map, authors_id_prob, authors_org_prob, fos_name_prob, publisher_prob, year_prob, authors_id_co, authors_org_co, fos_name_co, publisher_co, year_co, doc2vec_map
) for i in range(n_cpu))
```

Where authors_id_map, authors_org_map, fos_name_map, publisher_map, year_map, reference_map, authors_id_prob, authors_org_prob, fos_name_prob, publisher_prob, year_prob, authors_id_co, authors_org_co, fos_name_co, publisher_co, year_co, doc2vec_map are all very large c++ maps. Since I don't want to fork them to different processes, I make them memory maps instead. However, I end up getting the following error when my code gets to the Parallel() part:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "buildDF.pyx", line 473, in buildDF.build_DF
    results = Parallel(n_jobs = n_cpu, require="sharedmem", prefer="threads", max_nbytes=None)(delayed(build_DF_single)(
  File "/home/zhangji/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 1004, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/home/zhangji/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 808, in dispatch_one_batch
    islice = list(itertools.islice(iterator, big_batch_size))
  File "buildDF.pyx", line 475, in genexpr
    authors_id_map, authors_org_map, fos_name_map, publisher_map, year_map, reference_map, authors_id_prob, authors_org_prob, fos_name_prob, publisher_prob, year_prob, authors_id_co, authors_org_co, fos_name_co, publisher_co, year_co, doc2vec_map
  File "stringsource", line 207, in map.to_py.__pyx_convert_map_to_py_std_3a__3a_string____double
MemoryError
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on? What is "stringsource"?

Thanks!

Comment: Any hint or even random guesses are welcomed! I am very new to Cython, memmap, and multithreading!

Comment: Cython is auto-generating code to convert a Python map to std::map. The memory error is happening there. This is labelled "stringsource" because it comes from auto-generated Cython code rather than code you've written.

Comment: I don't know why you've got a memory error though - maybe your map contains circular references to itself?

Comment: On a closer look - I guess you're using `mmap` because you have huge datasets. There's absolutely no change of this being preserved when you convert to a C++ `std::map` - it'll load the entire dataset and then run out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on my comments:

The reference to `stringsource` is slightly confusing. It refers to utility code written in Cython which is generated internally by Cython. In this case the utility code is called to convert your Python map-like types to C++ `std::map<std::string, double>` (`__pyx_convert_map_to_py_std_3a__3a_string____double`).

The basic problem looks to be that you are trying to do two mutually contradictory things:

1. You are using a Python wrapping of `mmap` to load a set of large files without needing to load them into memory all at once.
2. You are converting all you data to C++ `std::map`, presumably because you hope it will be faster or that it can be run without the GIL.

The conversion to `std::map` is not a "transparent wrapper" - it makes a completely new copy. Therefore all the data is loaded out of your `mmap` and directly into memory - hence the `MemoryError` (I think - it's difficult to be definite when you have not provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

There is no obvious solution. Either you need to stick to using Python objects so that your `mmap` can be preserved or you need to implement a C++ class yourself that can load the data `mmap`-style to avoid the conversion to `std::map`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! I have a similar problem and this is a nice explanation!